# Надо вывести записи на определенной странице WordPress

Tags: wordpress, циклы, вывод, запись

Стоит задача вывести записи на определенной странице. Я как-то пробовал просто вставить данный код

```
<?php if( have_posts() ){ while( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

<?php } /* конец while */
}
?>
```

и думал, что записи будут отображаться. Но не тут-то было, никакого вывода записей нет. Кто-то мне подсказал, что есть возможность выводить записи с помощью рубрик на определенной странице, но и здесь вопрос - а как вывести рубрики на странице? В интернете куча бесполезных уроков, от просмотра которых одно раздражение, так как ни один из них не учит тому, на что ссылается в названии... Очень буду благодарен за помощь!!!

Answer (score 0):

В WordPress создаете пустую страницу с нужной постоянной ссылкой (slug), например, filter:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке темы `/wp-content/themes/моя_тема` создаете файл `page-filter.php`. В него вставляете ваш код. На сайте по адресу `http://сайт/filter/` видите результат.

P.S. Чтобы понять, почему так работает, почитайте про [иерархию шаблонов WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Ну вы мне просто подсказали как подключить страницу, у меня с этим проблем и не было. Вот я на эту новую страницу вставил цикл вывода записей и они не вывелись     http://dropmefiles.com/4lGBD

Comment: Чтобы понять, с чем у вас есть проблемы, а с чем нет, надо корректно формулировать вопрос. Я бы не тратил свое время на эту часть ответа.

Comment: а почему такой странный вывод на странице? какой код страницы в браузере? У вас проблема явно не в коде