# Как вывести все записи на определенной странице?

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Хотел бы создать страницу, где можно было вывести все записи, которые есть на сайте, в таком виде (см. рисунок ниже). Страница должна быть видна только администраторам. Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал страницу page-all.php (пример использовал отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677899/280093).

```
   <?php
   get_header(); ?>

            <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                <main id="main" class="site-main">
                    <div class="all-page">
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>
                    </div>
                </main><!-- #main -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php 
    get_footer();
```

Comment: А что вы сделали для решения этой задачи и что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Я создал страницу page-all.php (дополнил свой первый пост).

Comment: А где цикл вывода в вашем коде?

Comment: А мне вот интересно - для чего "хотел"-то? Тормозов добавить? Чем не устроил стандартный вывод (ну кроме оформления, которое можно решить версткой)?

Comment: @SeVlad ну чего ты, все норм. Он таблицей хочет вывести. Тормозов не будет. Вопрос простой, думаю, сейчас кто-нибудь ответит.

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну "таблица" - всего лишь форматирование стандартного архива. А отдельная страница - это уже html-карта сайта. Тормоза могут быть ещё какие.

Comment: Эта страница будет видна только администраторам.

Comment: Для администраторов и так всё есть в админке. Разве что добавить нужные столбцы в существующую таблицу. Так что мой вопрос становиться ещё более актуальным :)

Comment: Ида, где в вопросе про админку? Исправь вопрос, написав про цели задачи.

Comment: А вам написал про то, что страница будет видна только администраторам только потому что вы написали про нагрузку. Знаете как это сделать в панели администратора, окей, этот вариант тоже подойдет.

Comment: Если страница должна быть видна только администраторам, т.е. выводить надо в админке, то задача совсем другая, и решать ее надо иначе. Добавьте про администраторов в текст вопроса.

Comment: Добавил про администратора в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку в комментариях сказано, что "Эта страница будет видна только администраторам", задача сводится к тому, чтобы вывести дополнительные столбцы в консоли сайта. Колонки "название записи, рубрики и метки" уже присутствуют в консоли.

Добавьте следующий код в functions.php

```
// Добавить колонки
function filter_manage_post_columns( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['link'] = 'Ссылка';
    $defaults['featured_image'] = 'Изображение записи';
    $defaults['media'] = 'Медиафайлы';

    return $defaults;
}

add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'filter_manage_post_columns' );

// Вывод информации в колонках
function action_manage_post_columns_content( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column_name ) {
        case 'link':
            $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
            echo esc_url( $permalink );
            break;
        case 'featured_image':
            echo esc_html( get_featured_image_name( $post_id ) );
            break;
        case 'media':
            echo wp_kses_post( get_attached_media_names( $post_id ) );
            break;
        default:
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'action_manage_post_columns_content', 10, 2 );

// Вывести название изображения записи
function get_featured_image_name( $post_id ) {
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    if ( $post_thumbnail_id ) {
        $post_thumbnail_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'featured_preview' );

        return get_img_filename( $post_thumbnail_img[0] );
    }

    return '';
}

// Вывести прикрепленные изображения
function get_attached_media_names( $post_id ) {
    $images = get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id );
    $names = array();
    foreach ( $images as $img ) {
        $names[] = get_img_filename( $img->guid );
    }
    $names = implode( '<br>', $names );

    return $names;
}

// Получить только имя файла из ссылки
function get_img_filename( $link ) {
    $pos  = mb_strrpos( $link, '/' );
    $link = mb_substr( $link, $pos + 1 );

    return $link;
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вашем варианты выводится изображение (миниатюра) записи, а я писал про медиафайлы (изображения), которые прикреплены к данной записи.

Comment: Я дал вам главное - и самое неочевидное - какими хуками и как вывести дополнительные колонки в консоли. Полагал, что с мелочами вы сможете разобраться сами. Ну ОК, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. То что нужно!

Comment: @marchenkovby не умаляя решение коллеги,  куда более удобный и гибкий вариант -  https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/ :)

Comment: @SeVlad хорошее решение, но я уж привык все руками)))

Comment: @KAGGDesign а я уже предпочитаю не тратить время на изобретение и поддержку велосипедов. :) Хотя именно вместо этого плага (у меня он в моём списке "обязательных") уже думаю надо своё написать - заколебался настраивать одно и тоже на каждом сайте + сортировка в платной версии.

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо за ссылку на плагин!